# UPDATE update sem afetar todas as linhas em tabela sem ID

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Recebi uma tabela com informações de alguns clientes e precisava dar UPDATE porém como a tabela não tem ID e a maioria dos dados se repetem inclusive cpf existe alguma forma de dar o where apenas na linha selecionada?

Comment: Você projetou a tabela antes de cria-la? Fez o Diagrama de Entidades e Relacionamentos (DER)? Provavelmente se fosse bem projetada teria uma Chave Primária. Sugiro ver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186460/why-use-primary-keys

Answer (score 0):

Colocando varias condições no WHERE e um limit em 1 
EX:

```
UPDATE usuarios set name = 'SEU NOME' WHERE CPF = '123' and IDADE = '13' and RG = '433' and SOBRENOME = 'SOBRENOME' LIMIT 1
```